# How to change ListView only in GUI Thread (JavaFX)

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, viewcontroller

I've got following code in my MainViewController

```
public void initialize() {
    // Init
    Config.init();

    lvOnlineDevices.setItems(Config.OnlineDevicesList);
}
```

in Config:

```
public static ObservableList<Device> OnlineDevicesList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
public static DeviceSearcher deviceSearcher = new DeviceSearcher("192.168.180");

public static void init() {
    deviceSearcher.start();
}
```

in deviceSearcher (extends Thread):

```
public void run() {
    for (int i=1;i<10;i++){
        String tmpIp = _host+i;
        Config.OnlineDevicesList.add(new Device(tmpIp));
    }
}
```

My Problem is, i get following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread;
>   currentThread = Thread-3

**// UPDATE 1 Solution:**

in DeviceSearcher instead of

```
Config.OnlineDevicesList.add(new Device(tmpIp));
```

use

```
Platform.runLater(() -> Config.OnlineDevicesList.add(new Device(host)));
```

Comment: Ok, but i dont understand "JavaFX Application Thread". Can you do an example with the code above, please?

Comment: Just wrap `Config.OnlineDevicesList.add(new Device(tmpIp));` under `Platform.runLater()` as shown in the duplicate question.

Comment: I updated my question, thanks